# Paperclip on Windows: [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm getting this error in development when I try to upload a file.

```
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Chloe/AppData/Local/Temp/dfeacdebdd52607b78a0eca093c2ed7a20170510-45680-1dipvsw.jpg"
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/Chloe/AppData/Local/Temp/dfeacdebdd52607b78a0eca093c2ed7a20170510-45680-ns50at.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
```

I don't have `identify` command and it's not installed with ImageMagick (at least not anymore).

```
>dir "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16"\*.exe
 Directory of C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16

04/25/2017  06:26 AM           324,096 dcraw.exe
04/25/2017  06:24 AM        33,351,680 ffmpeg.exe
04/25/2017  06:24 AM           113,664 hp2xx.exe
04/25/2017  06:30 AM           201,728 imdisplay.exe
04/25/2017  06:30 AM           112,128 magick.exe
05/10/2017  08:53 PM         1,202,385 unins000.exe
               6 File(s)     35,305,681 bytes
```

I installed [ImageMagick](https://chocolatey.org/packages/imagemagick) from [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249770/papercliperrorsnotidentifiedbyimagemagickerror) question is similar, but out of date with no relevant answers.

Version: ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16, paperclip (5.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install

https://chocolatey.org/packages/imagemagick.tool

Instead. But you also have to adjust your path so ImageMagick's `convert` is before Window's `convert`

```
>where convert
C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\convert.exe
```

Oh, and use `refreshenv` and restart your server.